Получаю исключение wntdll.pdb not loaded
Здраствуйте, я столкнулся с исключением wntdll.pdb not loaded и мусором после операции сложения двух комплексных массивов.
Я полагаю, что проблема кроется в деструкторе, однако мне не хватает опыта, чтобы понять, что именно не верно.
Program.cpp
#include "ArrayOfComplex.h"
int main()
{
    
    Complex c1, c2, c3;
    cout << endl << "---------- ArrayOfComplex objects" << endl;
    cout << "Enter three complex numbers (format: real imaginary):" << endl;
    cin >> c1 >> c2 >> c3;

    
    cout << "c1 = " << c1 << " , c2 = " << c2 << " , c3 = " << c3 << endl;

    
    Complex ar1[] = { c1, c2, c3 };
    Complex ar2[] = { c3, c2, c1 };

    
    ArrayOfComplex ArObj1(3, ar1);
    ArrayOfComplex ArObj2(3, ar2);

    
    cout << "ArrayOfComplex ArObj1:" << endl << ArObj1;
    cout << "ArrayOfComplex ArObj2:" << endl << ArObj2;

    
    ArrayOfComplex ArObj3 = ArObj1 + ArObj2;
    ArrayOfComplex ArObj4 = ArObj1 - ArObj2;

    
    cout << "ArObj1 + ArObj2:" << endl << ArObj3;
    cout << "ArObj1 - ArObj2:" << endl << ArObj4;

    
    cout << "ArObj1[0] = " << ArObj1[0] << endl;

    
    ArrayOfComplex ArObj5;
    ArObj5 = ArObj1;
    cout << "ArObj5 (after assignment from ArObj1):" << endl << ArObj5;

    
    cout << "ArObj1 == ArObj2: " << (ArObj1 == ArObj2 ? "True" : "False") << endl;
    cout << "ArObj1 != ArObj2: " << (ArObj1 != ArObj2 ? "True" : "False") << endl;

    return 0;
}

Complex.h
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Complex
{
    float real;
    float imaginary;
public:
    // Constructors
    Complex();
    Complex(float real, float imaginary);
    Complex(const Complex& other);
    ~Complex();

    //Getters
    float getReal() const;
    float getImaginary() const;

    // Operator overloading
    Complex& operator=(const Complex& other);
    bool operator==(const Complex& other) const;
    bool operator!=(const Complex& other) const;
    Complex operator+(const Complex& other) const;
    Complex operator-(const Complex& other) const;
    Complex operator*(const Complex& other) const;
    Complex operator/(const Complex& other) const;

    // Friend functions for stream operators
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Complex& number);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Complex& number);

};

Complex.cpp
#include "Complex.h"

Complex::Complex() : real(0.0), imaginary(0.0) {}

Complex::Complex(float real, float imaginary) : real(real), imaginary(imaginary) {}

Complex::Complex(const Complex& other) {
    this->real = other.real;
    this->imaginary = other.imaginary;
}

Complex::~Complex()
{
}

float Complex::getReal() const
{
    return real;
}

float Complex::getImaginary() const
{
    return imaginary;
}

Complex& Complex::operator=(const Complex& other) {
    if (this != &other) {
        real = other.real;
        imaginary = other.imaginary;
    }
    return *this;
}


bool Complex::operator==(const Complex& other) const  
{
    return real == other.real && imaginary == other.imaginary;
}

bool Complex::operator!=(const Complex& other) const
{
    return !(*this == other);
}


Complex Complex::operator+(const Complex& other) const{
    return Complex(real + other.real, imaginary + other.imaginary);
}

Complex Complex::operator-(const Complex& other) const{
    return Complex(real - other.real, imaginary - other.imaginary);
}

Complex Complex::operator*(const Complex& other) const{
    return Complex(real * other.real - imaginary * other.imaginary,
        real * other.imaginary + imaginary * other.real);
}

Complex Complex::operator/(const Complex& other) const{
    float denominator = other.real * other.real + other.imaginary * other.imaginary;
    return Complex((real * other.real + imaginary * other.imaginary) / denominator,
        (imaginary * other.real - real * other.imaginary) / denominator);
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Complex& number)
{
    os << number.real << " + " << number.imaginary<<"*i";
    return os;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& is, Complex& number) {
    is >> number.real >> number.imaginary;
    return is;
}

ArrayOfComplex.h
#pragma once
#include "Complex.h"
class ArrayOfComplex
{
    unsigned int size;
    Complex* pComplex;
public:
    ArrayOfComplex();
    ArrayOfComplex(int size);
    ArrayOfComplex(int size, const Complex * complexArr);
    ~ArrayOfComplex();

    bool operator==(const ArrayOfComplex& other) const;
    bool operator!=(const ArrayOfComplex& other) const;
    ArrayOfComplex& operator=(const ArrayOfComplex& other);
    ArrayOfComplex operator+(const ArrayOfComplex& other) const;
    ArrayOfComplex operator-(const ArrayOfComplex& other) const;
    ArrayOfComplex operator*(const ArrayOfComplex& other) const;
    ArrayOfComplex operator/(const ArrayOfComplex& other) const;
    Complex& operator[](int i) const;

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const ArrayOfComplex& cArray);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, ArrayOfComplex& cArray);
};

ArrayOfComplex.cpp
#include "ArrayOfComplex.h"

ArrayOfComplex::ArrayOfComplex() : size(0), pComplex(nullptr){
    std::cout << "Default constructor called\n";
}
ArrayOfComplex::ArrayOfComplex(int size) : size(size), pComplex(new Complex[size]) {
    std::cout << "Parameterized constructor called\n";
}
ArrayOfComplex::ArrayOfComplex(int size, const Complex * complexArr) : size(size), pComplex(new Complex[size]) 
{
    std::cout << "Copy constructor called\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        pComplex[i] = Complex(complexArr[i]);
}
ArrayOfComplex::~ArrayOfComplex() { 
    std::cout << "Destructor called\n";
    if(pComplex != nullptr)
    delete[] pComplex;
}


bool ArrayOfComplex::operator==(const ArrayOfComplex& other) const
{

    if (size != other.size) return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if (pComplex[i] != other.pComplex[i]) return false;
    return true;
}

bool ArrayOfComplex::operator!=(const ArrayOfComplex& other) const
{
    return !(*this == other);
}

ArrayOfComplex& ArrayOfComplex::operator=(const ArrayOfComplex& other)
{
    std::cout << "Assignment operator called\n";
    if (*this != other) {
        if (this->pComplex != nullptr) 
            delete[] pComplex;

        size = other.size;
        pComplex = new Complex[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            pComplex[i] = other.pComplex[i];
    }
    return *this;
}

ArrayOfComplex ArrayOfComplex::operator+(const ArrayOfComplex & other) const
{
    std::cout << "Addition operator called\n";
    int i;
    ArrayOfComplex res((this->size >= other.size) ? this->size : other.size);

    for (i = 0; i < this->size && i < other.size; i++) 
        res[i] = (*this)[i] + other[i];

    for (; i < this->size; i++)
        res[i] = (*this)[i];

    for (; i < other.size; i++)
        res[i] = other[i];
    
    return res;
}

ArrayOfComplex ArrayOfComplex::operator-(const ArrayOfComplex& other) const
{
    int i;
    ArrayOfComplex res((this->size >= other.size) ? this->size : other.size);

    for (i = 0; i < this->size && i < other.size; i++) {
        res[i] = (*this)[i] - other[i];
    }

    for (; i < this->size; i++) {
        res[i] = (*this)[i];
    }

    for (; i < other.size; i++) {
        res[i] = other[i];
    }
    return res;
}

ArrayOfComplex ArrayOfComplex::operator*(const ArrayOfComplex& other) const
{
    int i;
    ArrayOfComplex res((this->size >= other.size) ? this->size : other.size);

    for (i = 0; i < this->size && i < other.size; i++) {
        res[i] = (*this)[i] * other[i];
    }

    for (; i < this->size; i++) {
        res[i] = (*this)[i];
    }

    for (; i < other.size; i++) {
        res[i] = other[i];
    }
    return res;
}

ArrayOfComplex ArrayOfComplex::operator/(const ArrayOfComplex& other) const
{
    int i;
    ArrayOfComplex res((this->size>=other.size)?this->size:other.size);

    for (i = 0; i < this->size && i < other.size; i++) {
        if(other[i].getReal() != 0 || other[i].getImaginary() != 0)
            res[i] = (*this)[i] / other[i];
    }
    
    for (; i < this->size; i++) {
        res[i] = (*this)[i];
    }

    for (; i < other.size; i++) {
        res[i] = other[i];
    }
    return res;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const ArrayOfComplex& cArray)
{
    os <<"Size: " << cArray.size << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < cArray.size; i++) {
        os << cArray.pComplex[i]<<endl;
    }
    return os;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& is, ArrayOfComplex& cArray)
{
    cout << "Please enter the size: ";
    is >> cArray.size;
    cArray.pComplex = new Complex[cArray.size];
    for (int i = 0; i < cArray.size; i++) {
        cin >> cArray.pComplex[i];
    }
    return is;
}

Complex& ArrayOfComplex::operator[](int i) const
{
    if (i < 0 || size <= i) 
    {
        cout << "Index out of range!" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    
    return pComplex[i];
}



Спасибо за любую помощь:)

Вы не туда смотрите. Стек вызовов посмотрите, какая строчка в какой вашей функции вызывала ошибку?

А если все-таки захочется разобраться с проблемой "wntdll.pdb not loaded", то для этого достаточно просто отметить в предложенном списке пункт Microsoft Symbol Servers и нажать на кнопку Load. Тогда недостающие отладочные символы для системных библиотек Windows будут автоматически подгружаться с серверов майкрософт.
